# Could not `chan` pass through RPC in Go?

Tags: go, rpc, channel

For the following code, get Message via RPC, why its Done field is nil?

Could not `chan` pass through RPC?

```golang
type Message struct {
    Text string
    Done chan bool
}

type (
    GetArgs struct {
        Key string
    }
    GetReply struct {
        Message  *Message
    }
)

// Client

func connect() *rpc.Client {
    client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", ":1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dialing:", err)
    }
    return client
}

func get(key string) *Message {
    client := connect()
    args := GetArgs{key}
    reply := GetReply{}
    err := client.Call("KV.Get", &args, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error:", err)
    }
    client.Close()
    return reply.Message
}

// Server

type KV struct {
    mu       sync.Mutex
    messages map[string]*Message
}

func server() {
    kv := new(KV)
    kv.messages = map[string]*Message{}

    done := make(chan bool)
    kv.messages["Jan"] = &Message{Text: "hello", Done: done}

    rpcs := rpc.NewServer()
    rpcs.Register(kv)
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error:", err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := l.Accept()
            if err == nil {
                go rpcs.ServeConn(conn)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        l.Close()
    }()
}

func (kv *KV) Get(args *GetArgs, reply *GetReply) error {
    kv.mu.Lock()
    defer kv.mu.Unlock()

    val, ok := kv.messages[args.Key]
    if ok {
        reply.Message = val
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    server()

    fmt.Printf("get() -> %v\n", get("Jan"))
    // Output:
    // get() -> &{hello <nil>}

}
```

Comment: Channel is not a serializable data type. You cannot pass channels through PRC. A channel is a process-specific concept, and RPC usually crosses process boundaries.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Aha, do make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. RPC arguments can only be those that are serializable by `encoding/gob`, and chans are [not one of them](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/gob)

> Functions and channels will not be sent in a gob. Attempting to encode such a value at the top level will fail. **A struct field of chan or func type is treated exactly like an unexported field and is ignored**.